# Pandas Python: take a subset of df by row labels while using re.IGNORECASE

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, ignore-case

I have df which looks like this:

```
print df_raw

Name              exp1
Name                  
UnweightedBase    1364
Base              1349
BFC_q5a1        34.18%
BFC_q5a2         2.93%
BFC_q5a3         1.86%
BFC_q5a4         1.93%
BFC_q5a5         0.84%
```

I want to build subset from the dataframe above using row labels however, I was like to use re.IGNORECASE but I'm not sure how.

without re.IGNORECASE the code looks like this:

```
subset_df = df_raw.loc[df_raw.index.isin(['BFC_q5a4', 'BFC_q5a5'])]
```

How can I change my code to make use of re.IGNORECASE for the code below:

```
subset_df = df_raw.loc[df_raw.index.isin(['bFc_q5A4', 'BfC_Q5a5'])]
```

note - I don't want to use str.lower or str.upper to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any neat way to search index labels in a case-insensitive way (`df.filter` is useful but doesn't appear to be able to ignore case unfortunately).

To get around this, you could make use of the series method `pd.Series.str.contains` which *can* ignore case:

```
subset_df = df[pd.Series(df.index).str.contains(regex, case=False).values]
```

The index is turned in a Series and then regex matching is applied. `regex` in this case could be something like `'bFc_q5A4|BfC_Q5a5'`. Case is ignored (using `case=False`).

Comment: that's a good idea. I'll try it out and see how it goes. thanks!

Comment: @Boosted_d16 No problem! Hope the code achieved what you needed.

Comment: I think you can use the select method to apply a filter to the index: `df_raw.select(lambda r: r.lower in my_list_of_rows)`

Comment: @Paul H, thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it out and see how it goes. Thanks.